# Filter data for all event

Tags: r, filter

I have a dataset `df` like this, which is the data collected from individuals using a repeating instrument:

```
ID <- c('A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A2', 'A2', 'A2', 'A2', 'A2', 'A3', 'A3', 'A3', 'A3', 'A4', 'A4', 'A4', 'A4', 'A4', 'A4', 'A4', 'A5', 'A5', 'A5', 'A5', 'A5', 'A5')
day_stat <- c(2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, NA)
adm_dat <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, '2020-10-12', NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, '2020-10-18', NA, NA)
adm_ever <- c(NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
df <- data.frame(ID, day_stat, adm_dat, adm_ever)
```

I am trying to filter the data like this:

```
df1 = df %>% filter(day_stat==1 | adm_dat!= NA | adm_ever==1)
```

Current result (not wanted):

[image: img]

#### Desired Output:

If **one** of these filter conditions is true for an `ID`, then keep **all** event data of that `ID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check for `NA` values use `is.na` and to select entire group use `group_by` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(any(day_stat==1 | !is.na(adm_dat) | adm_ever==1))

#    ID    day_stat adm_dat    adm_ever
#   <chr>    <dbl> <chr>         <dbl>
# 1 A1           2 NA               NA
# 2 A1           1 NA               NA
# 3 A1           1 NA               NA
# 4 A1           2 NA                1
# 5 A2           2 NA               NA
# 6 A2           2 NA               NA
# 7 A2           2 NA               NA
# 8 A2           1 2020-10-12       NA
# 9 A2           1 NA               NA
#10 A2           1 NA                2
# … with 13 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[any(day_stat==1 | !is.na(adm_dat) | adm_ever==1)], ID]
```